# How to use data in a column to find average, max, min, etc?

Tags: python, average, slice, file-read

I am trying to create a program that finds the max, min, average and the bmi of a data file. The file is 12 columns wide, however, I do not know how to use the data to create a bmi for each line? **side note:** *I cannot use Pandas, I am required to solve with standard line slicing etc.*

here's the example data.txt:

```
 Name Height(m) Weight(kg)
 Joe    1.82    72.57
 Mary   1.60    63.50
 Dion   1.90    90.71
 Kayla  1.72    66.31
 Jose   1.78    70.23
 Sofia  1.63    65.12
 Erik   1.98    92.21
 Sara   1.57    65.77

example result:
Name Height(m) Weight(kg) BMI
Joe   1.82     72.57     21.91
Mary  1.60     63.50     24.80
Dion  1.90     90.71     25.13
Kayla 1.72     66.31     22.41
Jose  1.78     70.23     22.17
Sofia 1.63     65.12     24.51
Erik  1.98     92.21     23.52
Sara  1.57     65.77     26.68

Average 1.75   73.30     23.89
Max 1.98       92.21     26.68
Min 1.57       63.50     21.91
```

Here's my code so far:

```
 def reading_file():
    file=open("data.txt")
    headers = file.readline().strip()
    print("headers:\n{}\n\nrest of file:".format(headers))
    total_height=0
    total_weight=0
    bmi=0
    for line in file:
        line_list=line.strip()
        height=line_list[12:24]
        weight=line_list[24:36]
        print(height,weight)

        total_height+=float(height)
        avg_height=total_height/8

        total_weight+=float(weight)  
        avg_weight=total_weight/8
        avg_bmi=float(avg_weight)/float(avg_height)**2
     print("average bmi:",avg_bmi)
     print("average weight:",avg_weight)
     print("average height:",avg_height)


 print(reading_file())
```

my result:
    headers:
    Name        Height(m)   Weight(kg)

```
rest of file:
1.82         72.57
1.60         63.50
1.90         90.71
1.72         66.31
1.78         70.23
1.63         65.12
1.98         92.21
1.57         65.77
average bmi: 23.93551020408163
average weight: 73.3025
average height: 1.75
None
```

How do I create a bmi for each column?

Comment: Opening the file in write mode probably isn't a great idea; it will wipe all the data it currently contains.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a basic python tutorial as this sort of thing is usually covered very early in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df
Out[20]: 
    Name  Height(m)  Weight(kg)
0    Joe       1.82       72.57
1   Mary       1.60       63.50
2   Dion       1.90       90.71
3  Kayla       1.72       66.31
4   Jose       1.78       70.23
5  Sofia       1.63       65.12
6   Erik       1.98       92.21
7   Sara       1.57       65.77

# calculate the BMI column 
df['BMI'] = df['Weight(kg)'] / (df['Height(m)'] ** 2)

df
Out[22]: 
    Name  Height(m)  Weight(kg)        BMI
0    Joe       1.82       72.57  21.908586
1   Mary       1.60       63.50  24.804687
2   Dion       1.90       90.71  25.127424
3  Kayla       1.72       66.31  22.414143
4   Jose       1.78       70.23  22.165762
5  Sofia       1.63       65.12  24.509767
6   Erik       1.98       92.21  23.520559
7   Sara       1.57       65.77  26.682624

# use the describe() method to, well, *describe* the numerical columns in your file
df.describe()
Out[23]: 
       Height(m)  Weight(kg)        BMI
count   8.000000    8.000000   8.000000
mean    1.750000   73.302500  23.891694
std     0.147067   11.583038   1.680321
min     1.570000   63.500000  21.908586
25%     1.622500   65.607500  22.352048
50%     1.750000   68.270000  24.015163
75%     1.840000   77.105000  24.885372
max     1.980000   92.210000  26.682624
```

I'll leave getting *just* mean, max, and min as an exercise for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into answering this, but i should've said that I cannot use pandas, I will edit the post to encompass it.